# How to create the preview mode for the email-readers like Gmail, Hotmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, tinymce

How to make the preview mode for the email-readers like hotmail gmail for the TinyMCE text editor

Comment: What exactly do you mean with **preview mode**?

Comment: please give us some more information about what you want to achieve and what you did already + your tinymce configuration. what you wrote here is not sufficient - we cannot guess what you want

Comment: Normally, most of the editor has the preview mode to see how it looks as a plain text & HTML view in the real scenario. But the things i need is, if i write a mail and i want to see how the Email Client Reader like Hotmail, Gmail, Outlook, thunderbird parse the HTML and plain text content of the TinyMCE editor in the real scenario in the inbox of Gmail, Hotmail, Outlook, Thunderbird. In this way, i was trying to make some plugin for the TinyMCE editor. Is there any free JS libraries to work with it

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to get the contents of the tinyMCE editor and let the user see how it looks, you can use this command:

```
    var previewcontent=tinyMCE.getContent();
//append preview content to the preview box now.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Normally, most of the editor has the preview mode to see how it looks as a plain text & HTML view in the real scenario. But the things i need is, if i write a mail and i want to see how the Email Client Reader like Hotmail, Gmail, Outlook, thunderbird parse the HTML and plain text content of the TinyMCE editor in the real scenario in the inbox of Gmail, Hotmail, Outlook, Thunderbird. In this way, i was trying to make some plugin for the TinyMCE editor. Is there any free JS libraries to work with it

Thank you!!!

Comment: Deepak Lamichhane, as far as I know, this is not possible, as outlook, hotmail, gmail, thunderbird, ... all render their email content in different ways. I've had some of my emails that I send through a php script look perfect in hotmail, but it looked really ugly in gmail. This is because all of those viewers have different stylesheets that apply to the message, or involuntarily apply to the message.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard of this tool: **[Fractal](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/fractal-html-css-validation-for-e-mails/)** that will do the hard work of knowing the quirks of many mail clients for you. I don't know what you can do with the Beta, only heard of it, but it's worth a look imho.

On the About page of Getfractal, you can follow the 2 links (Campaign Monitor and Email Standard Project) and discover how HTML email is doomed. These are the references if you want to do it manually as quite everybody else.

For manually testing, you can create an email account (or maybe a list in your contacts) that will forward automatically your test mail to a dozen of email address you can use as tests (on gmail, hotmail, Yahoo! mail, etc)